# Kotlin class name is wrong

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I've got a simple kotlin file with a function that maps an enum to a Fragment Class name for an Android application. For some reason the returned string is always "d".

```
 fun getClassNameForType(type: ContentOuterClass.Onboarding.ItemCase) : String? =
when(type) {
    ContentOuterClass.Onboarding.ItemCase.EMAIL -> EmailFragment::class.simpleName
    ContentOuterClass.Onboarding.ItemCase.HORIZONTAL_TWO_BUTTON -> HorizontalTwoButtonFragment::class.simpleName

    ContentOuterClass.Onboarding.ItemCase.VERTICAL_TWO_BUTTON -> VerticalTwoButtonFragment::class.simpleName

    ContentOuterClass.Onboarding.ItemCase.PRACTICE_SCHEDULE -> PracticeScheduleFragment::class.simpleName

    ContentOuterClass.Onboarding.ItemCase.SINGLE_BUTTON -> SingleButtonFragment::class.simpleName
    ContentOuterClass.Onboarding.ItemCase.SUBSCRIBE -> SubscribeFragment::class.simpleName

    else -> null
}
```

What's also odd is that when I hardcode a string that string comes back correctly. I've tried the various suggestions for getting the class name for java and kotlin classes with no luck (ie `qualifiedName` , `simpleName`, `::class.java.simpleName`, etc).

Comment: Sounds like you are using Proguard

Comment: Please show several examples of how you call the function. Then show the output and explain what you expect instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your classes obfuscated by [Proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) which changes your class names. If you want to prevent obfuscation on your class names. you can add these lines in your `proguard-rules.pro` files:

```
-keepnames class your.package.name.ClassName {}
```